# Generate Summary using Resharper not working

Tags: c#, resharper

I had VS 2015 and Resharper and i could generate methods Summary by clicking on methods name and the light bulb suggestion was "Generate method summary".

[image]

After i've update to VS2017 i dont have this suggestion anymore. Does anybody else had this issue?
I know the Summary can be generated using "///" but this does not complete automatically the attributes:

```
/// <param name="isMap"></param>
```

I would like

```
/// <param name="isMap">Is map.</param>
```

Comment: Check that you have "StyleCop plugin" installed in ReSharper | Extensions Manager.

Comment: Wonderful @AlexanderKurakin! That was the problem. Thanks!

Comment: To be blunt, if a tool, such as GhostDoc or ReSharper/Stylecop in this case, can create an acceptable summary, you don't need it, because at that point the method name and parameter names and their types make the behavior of the method self-evident. In the typical case, such tools will not be able to create acceptable summaries though and you're better off editing them in manually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

StyleCop plugin for ReSharper provides such enhanced summary generation. It looks like you had such plugin installed into ReSharper in VS2015. Since you moved to VS2017 and then integrated ReSharper into such VS version, ReSharper | Extension Manager is empty by default. So, you need to install "StyleCop by JetBrains" plugin via the Manager.